# WordPress hide CSS element

Tags: php, css, wordpress, hide

I want to hide save&share button

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-none btn-sm btn-save-design dg-tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Save &amp; Share" onclick="design.save()">
                    <i class="fa fa-save"></i>
                </button>
```

I tried to hide using

```
.btn-save-design {display: none;}
```

But nothing happens

[image]

Please share a CSS code or PHP code to put it.

Comment: try with inline `style-sheet` and than see

Comment: Add important to the to the CSS like this .btn-save-design {display: none !important;}

Answer (score 1):

probably some other css override your `display:none`.

So use `!important` as `display:none!important` (If you use bootstrap use this option)

But better to  change the order of rules in css (the `display:none` before the other style of button) as:

```
.btn-save-design {display: none;}//first
.btn{
    //other style...
}
```

Comment: Not Working, any other suggestions?

Comment: Take a look in F12 and tell me what you happend to button on click in css section

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn-save-design i.fa.fa-save {
     display:none;
}
```

Try this one

Comment: This will just hide the icon inside the button - leaving the OP with an empty button still.

Comment: can you please provide us the live link ?

Comment: Not Working, any other suggestions?

Comment: can you please share the link?